# How can I resolve the 'Undefined variable' and 'Attempt to read property' warnings in WordPress updates?

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is the error hope someone could guild me.

Current version: 6.2.2

Warning: Undefined variable $checkout in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-automatic-updater.php on line 175 This site will not receive automatic updates for new versions of WordPress.

You have the latest version of WordPress.

Warning: Attempt to read property "current" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 41 Warning: Attempt to read property "locale" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 43 Warning: Attempt to read property "locale" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 45 Warning: Attempt to read property "locale" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 51 Warning: Attempt to read property "current" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 67 Warning: Attempt to read property "response" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 77
Warning: Attempt to read property "current" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 163 Warning: Attempt to read property "locale" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 164  Warning: Attempt to read property "locale" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 173

Warning: Attempt to read property "locale" on bool in /volume1/web_packages/wordpress/wp-admin/update-core.php on line 182
This localized version contains both the translation and various other localization fixes.

I have try replacing the file and fix some scrip but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first error may be causing the subsequent ones. The first error looks to be a bug with core. There does not appear to be an existing ticket for the bug on WordPress Trac.